# Выполнение удаленной процедуры по расписанию посредством pg_cron

Tags: postgresql

Помогите разобраться как посредством pg_cron запускать удаленные процедуры через db_link ?

Ниже приведене код по созданию db_link, добавлению вызова процедуры в pg_cron, и проверки что процеда через db_link из pgAdmin под пользоватлем postgres выполняется корректно.

Когда же работает scheduler-р, то возвращается ошибка -  `status: failed,  return_message: "connection failed"`

Как исправить проблему и настроить pg_cron для запуска удаленной процедуры через dblink в postgres 15?

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dblink_dev', 'dbname=dev host=localhost user=fetcher password=password');

SELECT cron.schedule(
        'schedule_delete_old_data', 
        '1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * *', 
        $$SET statement_timeout = '4min 30s'; PERFORM dblink_exec('dblink_dev', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()'); SET statement_timeout = '0';$$
    );  

SELECT dblink_exec('dblink_dev', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()');
```

Ниже вариант тоже не дал результата и вернул ту же ошибку.

```
SELECT cron.schedule(
    'schedule_delete_old_ohlcv_data', 
    '1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * *', 
    $$SET statement_timeout = '4min 30s'; PERFORM dblink('dbname=dev host=localhost user=fetcher password=password', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()');SET statement_timeout = '0';$$);
```

Comment: dblink_connect-то сделайте. Он не глобальный, а на вполне конкретную текущую сессию и только в ней одной и доступен. Впрочем, ради одного вызова и вовсе нет нужды дёргать dblink_connect+dblink_exec вместо одного комбинированного dblink

Comment: а можно попросить вас примерчик ? и нужны ли специфичные права для учетки postgres?